# NSController with own xib file but no view

Tags: macos, cocoa, menubar, nsmenu

I'm creating a MenuBar-Application with a couple of popup-windows, a NSMenu and some regular windows for settings and stuff like that.
I created a NSController to hold all my StatusBar stuff together and notify the popup to open and close.
The popup has it's own PopupWindowController and xib file wich works like a charm. But i can't get it to work with the NSMenu (in my case it's subclassed as RightClickMenu)

In IB i created an other .xib called StatusBarController.xib (with StatusBarController as the file's owner) with the menu and linked it to the outlet.
...

```
@class RightClickMenu;
@interface StatusBarController : NSController <NSMenuDelegate> {
    IBOutlet RightClickMenu *rightClickMenu;
}
@property (nonatomic, retain) RightClickMenu *rightClickMenu;
...
```

My AppDelegate has a IBOutlet StatusBarController property and a the main .xib which is linked to the NScontroller object.

```
@class StatusBarController;
@interface MyAppDelegate : NSObject <NSApplicationDelegate> {
    IBOutlet StatusBarController *statusBarController;
...
```

Hope you can help...

cheers

Comment: Are you using NSController for bindings? It's not your typical controller; you usually use its subclasses NSObjectCOntroller or NSArrayController. The NSWindowControllers and NSVIewControllers are not related to NSController at all.

Comment: Ok. I'm using a NSViewController for the popup-window but i'm not sure how to handle the StatusBarController. NSObjectController would be better, but it's still not working... i logged `NSLog(@"%o", self.rightClickMenu) => 0` but it seems not loaded. i tried to subclass StatusMenuContoller from NSViewController and logged `NSLog(@"%o", self.view)` which gave me the id...

Comment: You should use `%@` instead of `%o` to print objects; try that instead? Also, let me rephrase: NSObjectControllers/NSArrayControllers/NSControllers are not meant to be used as the controller of an graphical interface, but rather as a controller for bindings/Core Data. I would subclass `NSObject` instead to make the StatusBarController because it doesn't look like you're managing a view or a window with it. Also, sorry if I digress, because I'm confused at the structure of your application/what the problem is :)

Comment: My main issue is that i'm trying to write this controller with a property IBOutlet RightClickMenu *menu which is stored in its own StatusBarController.xib and the property is always (null)...

Comment: @Jorn - I'm having the same problem here. The NSMenu is always null even through it appears that I've linked it correctly.

Comment: Jörn, look at what Vervious wrote. Are you using NSController to control a view or window? What is the structure of your application? What is `RightClickMenu`?

Answer (score 1):

your variable! is an outlet but your property is not

IB uses KVC to set outlets and that will find your property which will use _variable

---

BTW just in case:

you gotta handle the loading yourself EXCEPT if you subclass NSViewController

in init of the controller you do a [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibName:@"bla" owner:self];